# Using GLUT Libraries in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, glut

I'm trying to use glut in Java, and I use eclipse as my IDE.

So, what's your suggestion for using it(How should I do it)? Is there any tutorial on that? Is there anything better than glut for using in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you trying to do with OpenGL? If you are making a game, see [`LWJGL`](http://lwjgl.org). If you are trying to make just a graphic application, see [`JOGL`](https://jogamp.org/jogl/www/).

Some tutorials on setting it up.

- [`LWJGL Tutorial Series`](http://goharsha.com/lwjgl-tutorial-series/) -- My Tutorials with OpenGL 3.3 Core
- [`JOGL Tutorial`](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_Tutorial)
- [`LWJGL Tutorials` -- See the Tutorials Section](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Hope these resources help

Comment: No difference in that respect between JOGL and LWJGL ,both are OpenGL wrappers.LWJGL doesn't supply any game dev features.

Comment: @MichaelIV That's true, but LWJGL is more user friendly for me with it's static design.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [**JOGL**](https://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) instead. JOGL will provide use all that GLUT does and a lot more! There is plenty of documentation about it online.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [JOGL](https://jogamp.org/jogl/www/), one of the best OpenGL bindings for Java (also includes GLUT). There are a lot of tutorials on their, as well as other websites.